# Stop cube and then continue

Tags: python, game-engine

BGE question.

I have applied movement to a cube with apply.movment([0,1,0], True).

How can I stop it if is near a cylinder that is timed to flick from 5 to 5 seconds, and after to continue?

Let's consider the cylinder a barrier.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean gameplay stop?
If yes make a ***variable***.give it a name like gameplay.
now make that variable True to make it boolean

```py
import bge
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
w_key = cont.sensors["w_key"] # This is to get the keyboard sensor

#The gameplay variable make it playable or not:
gameplay = True

if gameplay == True and w_key.positive:
    apply.movment([0,1,0], True)
elif gameplay == False and w_key.positive:
    print("You can't move!")
```